# Who / What am I? - If anyone is still even remotely a fan

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm a mega form, which is rather new
>
> With what's in my hand, you'll eat a stew
>
> You will hear my name during magic shows
>
> Oh, did I mention I have six toes
>
> We used to have three forms, but now we have four
>
> Just temporary, but maybe we get even more..
>
> As third form I sleep inside a ball
>
> As my current form however, I win them all
>
> We exist since 1995
>
> Six generations, with the seventh soon to be alive

Hint 1:

> TCG

Hint 2:

> JP

Hint 3:

> [image]

Comment: I think this was pretty easy - the hints certainly weren't necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're :

> Mega-Alakazam

Let me time to explain each sentence

I'm a mega form, which is rather new

> mega evolutions are new in the world of pokemon

With what's in my hand, you'll eat a stew

> a spoon

You will hear my name during magic shows

> abra kadabra alakazam is the typical magic formula

Oh, did I mention I have six toes

> well, just look a picture of it

We used to have three forms, but now we have four

> 3 basics form + the mega evolution

Just temporary, but maybe we get even more..

> Mega evolution isn't a permanent state, but maybe in the future...

As third form I sleep inside a ball

> inside the pokeball

As forth however, I win them all

> mega evolutions are known for beeing very strongs.

We exist since 1995

Six generations, with the seventh soon to be alive

> y'all know POKEMONS my friends :)

Comment: I'm sad(???) to say you beat me to it.

Comment: I saw my chance and I took it :D

Comment: Ugh, I was so close D:

Comment: Can't believe I got both Deusovi and question_asker, let me call my Mom :')

Comment: All correct, except for `You're:` ;P I rephrased a sentence in my question. Perhaps it was a bit **too** easy, but I didn't knew how many here would be fans. ;)

Comment: Maybe it fits a bit better now !